# android CustomView differentiate events using Gesture with dispatchTouchEvent always return false

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created a CustomListView, it contains override method dispatchTouchEvent with return false as below

I need to differentiate between click, long click and double tap.?

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }

        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }
        return false;
    }

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }

    final GestureDetector gestureDetector = (new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            super.onLongPress(e);
            Log.e("test", "Long press detected");
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.e("test", "Double Tab detected");
            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
        }
    }));
```

provide suggesstion.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your gestureDetector before setting the onTouchListener to a view. You also have to provide your gestureListener in the onTouchEvent like this:

```
 final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
             ...
        } //etc
    }

 viewHolder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event, simpleOnGestureListener);
        }
    });
```